# Does not generate directory dist when running ng build --prod

Tags: angular, build

I'm working on a project in Angular 4 and when running ng serve and ng build the project works but when running ng build --prod does not work, this warning happens.
  94% asset optimization (node: 88241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({ (node: 88241) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
I've searched a lot but nothing helped me.
Is there any way to view a log when it builds the build --prod?

[Image of the error that happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vngnk.png)

Comment: Please share your package.json file and Angular-Cli.json

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the dependencies installed in your node_modules dir are messed up. Try deleting node_modules and running npm install again.

If this doesn't help, install the latest Angular CLI (currently it's 1.4.5), generate a new project, and replace the content of the sections dependencies and devDependencies in your project's package.json with the ones from the generated project. After that delete node_modules and run npm install again.